# How to convert this MySQL query to Yii2 ActiveQuery format?

Tags: php, yii2

This is my MySQL query

```
SELECT dc.`dc_key`
,@delivered_qty := (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(dd.`qty`),0)
    FROM `delivery_detail` dd
    WHERE dd.`item_key` = 1
    AND dd.dc_key = dc.dc_key
) AS delivered_qty
,@borrowed_qty := (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(bd.`qty`),0)
    FROM `borrow_detail` bd
    WHERE bd.`item_key` = 1
    AND bd.`voided` = 0
    AND bd.`returned` = 0
    AND bd.`dc_key` = dc.`dc_key`
) AS borrowed_qty
, (@delivered_qty - @borrowed_qty) AS available_qty
FROM `delivery_catalog` dc
WHERE (@delivered_qty - @borrowed_qty) > 0
LIMIT 1
```

This is my result without the limit
[image: query result]

This is what I have tried so far but to no good.

```
$SQL = ''
. 'SELECT dc.`dc_key` '
. ',@delivered_qty := (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(dd.`qty`),0) '
. '    FROM `delivery_detail` dd '
. '    WHERE dd.`item_key` = :item_key '
. '    AND dd.dc_key = dc.dc_key '
. ') AS delivered_qty '
. ',@borrowed_qty := (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(bd.`qty`),0) '
. '    FROM `borrow_detail` bd '
. '    WHERE bd.`item_key` = :item_key '
. '    AND bd.`voided` = 0 '
. '    AND bd.`returned` = 0 '
. '    AND bd.`dc_key` = dc.`dc_key` '
. ') AS borrowed_qty '
. ', (@delivered_qty - @borrowed_qty) AS available_qty '
. 'FROM `delivery_catalog` dc '
. 'WHERE (@delivered_qty - @borrowed_qty) > 0 '
//. 'LIMIT 1 '
. '';

$rawData = DeliveryDetail::findBySql($SQL, [':item_key' => $item_key])->ALL();

print_r($rawData);

return;
```

It returns an empty array.

I want to utilized the query builder of yii2 for a clean code.

Comment: Try this 

http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/select-query-joins/

Comment: you can always use raw sql to do that instead of active record, it is much faster

Comment: @Robert, That's what I did, but it does not seem to work. It returned an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$SQL = ''
. 'SELECT dc.`dc_key` '
. ',@delivered_qty := (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(dd.`qty`),0) '
. '    FROM `delivery_detail` dd '
. '    WHERE dd.`item_key` = :item_key '
. '    AND dd.dc_key = dc.dc_key '
. ') AS delivered_qty '
. ',@borrowed_qty := (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(bd.`qty`),0) '
. '    FROM `borrow_detail` bd '
. '    WHERE bd.`item_key` = :item_key '
. '    AND bd.`voided` = 0 '
. '    AND bd.`returned` = 0 '
. '    AND bd.`dc_key` = dc.`dc_key` '
. ') AS borrowed_qty '
. ', (@delivered_qty - @borrowed_qty) AS available_qty '
. 'FROM `delivery_catalog` dc '
. 'WHERE (@delivered_qty - @borrowed_qty) > 0 '
//. 'LIMIT 1 '
. '';

$rows = \Yii::$app->db->createCommand($SQL)
            ->bindParam(":item_key", $item_key)
            ->queryAll();
```

Should work. You can use datareader via `query()` if result set is big.

To use query builder you need to rewrite this query, which actually can be done without variables in columns.

I think this can be rewritten to:

```
SELECT dc.`dc_key` ,
IFNULL(SUM(dd.`qty`),0) as delivered_qty,
IFNULL(SUM(bd.`qty`),0) as borrowed_qty
LEFT JOIN `delivery_detail` dd ON dd.`item_key` = :item_key AND dd.dc_key = dc.dc_key 
LEFT JOIN `borrow_detail` bd ON 
         bd.`item_key` = :item_key 
    AND bd.`voided` = 0 
    AND bd.`returned` = 0 
    AND bd.`dc_key` = dc.`dc_key` 
FROM `delivery_catalog` dc
GROUP BY dc.`dc_key`
HAVING delivered_qty - borrowed_qty > 0
```

`(@delivered_qty - @borrowed_qty) AS available_qty` this can be done in PHP, and such query can be converted to query builder without problems.